# Переход в button navigation activity

Tags: android-fragment, activity, button, android-navigation-drawer, android-button

у меня есть проблема. Я создал активность в стиле button navigation, когда я пр нижней панели нажимаю, экран переключается между 5 активностями которые у меня добавлены. Но мне надо сделать чтобы открывалась еще одна активность, при нажатии на кнопку. Я попробовал несколько способов, но у меня вылетает эмулятор и на компьютере и на телефоне при запуске.

```
package my.file.my;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.navigation_home,
                R.id.navigation_dashboard,
                R.id.navigation_notifications,
                R.id.navigation_four,
                R.id.navigation_five)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, trade.class);
                    startActivity(intent); finish();
                }catch (Exception e){

                }
            }
        });
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот сюда

```
  AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new 
  AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.navigation_home,
            R.id.navigation_dashboard,
            R.id.navigation_notifications,
            R.id.navigation_four,
            R.id.navigation_five)
            .build();
```

допиши новую, шестую, активность. И если не получается, описание ошибки в студию

Comment: у меня в этих строчках не добавляется новая активность. Ее нет в подсказках и когда я ее пишу от руки она просто выделяется красным

Comment: Значит что-то неправильно делаете

Comment: а ,ну да ,спасибо что объяснили....